# finding source IP of a workstation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to determine which is  the main source IP on a workstation (used when connection goes via default gateway)

There are many IPs/interfaces on a workstation (many private subnets, virtual box, which script should ignore).

I found %computername% but it is not reliable because it very often returns private IP of virtualbox network.

I was thinking to find it on "route PRINT"

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('route PRINT -4 ^| findstr 0.0.0.0') do set _IPaddr=%%a
echo IP is: %_IPaddr%
```

but the "findstr 0.0.0.0" returns also other routes:

```
>route PRINT -4 | findstr /s /i /m 0.0.0.0
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.170.44.1    10.170.44.150      2
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.177.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.170.44.150    257
```

how to tell to findstr to return only the first line beginning with white spaces and then 0.0.0.0? (default route line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you've some superfluous arguments there:

- `/s` is for searching dirs and subdirs
- `/i` is for case-insensitive which makes no sense when searching for numbers

This should do what you want:

`route PRINT -4 | findstr /c:" 0.0.0.0"`

The `/c` tells `findstr` to search for the subsequent string literally, i.e. preventing it from stripping the leading space.

Alternatively you could just get `route` to do a bit more of the work for you:

`route PRINT 0.0.0.0 | findstr "0.0.0.0"`